# jQuery Dialog Not Closing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My alert is reached and works, but the close method is not working.  Any idea why ?

My javascript:

```
  var myDialog = $('#divContactUs');

  myDialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               title: "Send Us A Note:",
               modal: true,
               buttons: [{
                   id: "btn-send",
                   text: "Send",
                   click: function () {
                       // you can now use the reference to the dialog
                       myDialog.dialog("close");
                       alert('test');
                   }
               }]

           });
       });
```

And my html:

```
<div id="divContactUs" style="display:none">
Name: &nbsp <input type="text" name="Name" /><br />
Email: &nbsp <input type="text" name="Email" /><br />
Phone: &nbsp <input type="text" name="Phone" /><br />
Message:<br />
<textarea name="Message"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scope of the button click `$(this)` refers to the button, not the modal. I would set the modal selector to a variable first then reference it later;

```
var myDialog = $('#divContactUs');

myDialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Send Us A Note:",
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        id:"btn-send",
        text: "Send",
        click: function() {
            // you can now use the reference to the dialog
            myDialog.dialog("close")
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hmmm.  I thought that would do the trick, but I am still having the same problem.  Any other ideas ?

Comment: I have modified it many times in the past hour or so....I added my most recent code above.

Comment: If I add the alert before the close method, then the alert works, but in it's current position I do not reach the alert.

Comment: What modal library is this you're using?

Comment: I just changed the version of jQuery and jQuery UI and it's working fine now.  Thanks Jivings :)

Answer (score 0):

You script is working. Don't forget to add semicolon `;` add the end of your lines `$(this).dialog("close");`.

Here's a jsFiddle to prove it [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVfXf/4/)

Comment: You learned me something but I will keep my semicolons "just to be safe".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IE throws an error "Unspecified Error".

```
try{ 
    $(selector).dialog("close");.
}catch(e){
    $(selector).parent().hide();
}
```